# Cannot remove certain character from a string. PHP

Tags: php, special-characters

I have a string(retrieved from another website using cURL. With the string I am trying to replace a certain character with nothing, no space, just get rid of it.

```
foreach($propinfo_desc_div as $child)
{
    // ONLY SHOW STRINGS LONGER THAN 10 CHARS
    $strlen = strlen($child->nodeValue);
    if($strlen > 10)
    {
        $description = str_replace(htmlspecialchars('&#194;'),'', $child->nodeValue);
        echo $description;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Some info on the character:

- ASCII Char: Â
- `ASCII Code: '&#194';`
- ASCII Description: Latin Capital Letter A Circumflex

string example:

```
 fully serviced daily. Â Â Spend the evenings relaxing in the frie
```

Solution by @Whoughton

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I spent a little more time looking at it, I believe this should work a little better:

```
$char = utf8_decode('this is a string with charÂ in it Â couple of times');
$r = utf8_decode('Â');
$upd = str_replace($r, '', $char);
```

This produces, for me:

```
Source: string(51) "this is a string with charÂ in it Â couple of times" 
Function: str_replace('Â', '', $char)
Output: string(49) "this is a string with char in it couple of times"
```

---

*Old answer removed...*

Comment: I'm not even sure if I'm using the htmlspecialchars function correctly. I have since changed the space to ''. but i want to get rid of the char all together. i have also tried it with just the char str_replace('Â','', $sting)

Comment: If that didn't work, then it is not identifying the character correctly it would seem. Do you happen to have a sample input string?

Comment: Odd that while I used an A with circumflex it sure looks like an A with a tilde up here...

Comment: this is causes all sorts of issues for me. doing the str_replace on the tilde did **râ€š**

Comment: Are you setting a charset in either your meta tags or in the webserver header? Something like: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: you clever sausage. i was actually testing this on a blank php page. that did that trick mr @whoughton. you deserve cookies, but i can only supply tick